# org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection in red5

Tags: red5, openlaszlo

After some time of running red5 server, this following error occurred, thereby disconnecting the connection. I don't know why this is happening. Can anyone give a solution to this problem?

```
[WARN] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-3] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - 
Closing RTMPMinaCOnnection from x.x.x.x : 3575 to x.x.x.x(in:3415 out 3217), 
with id 1 due to long handshake
```

Answer (score 1):

Which revision of red5 are you exactly using? There are major changes between the different revisions.

Unfortunately your issue can be caused by quite a lot of different things.

For example this error can happen if you restart the red5 server while people are still connected to the old instance. When they try to reconnect without refreshing the browser you can see tons of such logs (but actually there is no error at that moment).

There are also config params in the red5.properties to modify the timeout, but you should first try to fix it by debuging your app-logic before starting to playaround with timeout parameters.

Comment: I am using red5 0.8 and use red5 recorder i am facing same issue any idea on it?